# Using user specified arguments as keys in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have data coming back from an API as JSON. In this there is a results array with result object/hashes with between 5 and 9 keys - id, url, title, type, that sort of thing.

If I want to strip out the unnecessary stuff and return an array of results with just title and url, I can do this:

```
function getTitleAndUrl(yourDataObject){ 
var results = yourDataObject.results;
var len = results.length;
var out = [];

for(var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
    out.push({
        title: results[i].title,
        url: results[i].url
    });
}
  return out;
};
```

And I get all the results with just title and url.

How could I make it so that some arguments passed into a function become the equivalent of 'title' and 'url'?
The idea is like this:

```
function getSpecificData(yourData, arg1, arg2){
  var results = yourData.results;
  var len = results.length;
  var out = [];

    for( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ){
    out.push({
        arg1: results[i].arg1,
        arg2: results[i].arg2
    });
}
  return out;
}
```

Where `arg1` and `arg2` could be title, url like the previous example or id, description etc.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects . It will do a lot of good to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in arg1 and arg2 as strings then this should work:

```
function getSpecificData(yourData, arg1, arg2){
  var results = yourData.results;
  var len = results.length;
  var out = [];

  for( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ){
    var data = {};
    data[arg1] = results[i][arg1];
    data[arg2] = results[i][arg2];
    out.push(data);
  }
  return out;
}
```

Working Example - http://jsfiddle.net/LasCB/1/

Comment: That's brilliant. So close, but just couldn't get my head around it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the `for` loop:

```
var obj = {};

obj[ key1 ] = value1;
obj[ key2 ] = value2;

out.push( obj );
```

Where `key1` and `key2` are the keys you want to use.

Comment: Yeah that works and the answer above gives me the flexibility I need. Thanks all